# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue on Xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

everybody

I was developing an iOS app on Xcode 8.2 with cocoapods. And I've upgraded Xcode from v8.2 to v8.3.2 and faced many warnings with corrupted path for every cocoapods framework.

**"Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: Non-portable path to file 'VVolumesPProjectiiOSPpodsTTarget Support FilesAAlamofire-prefix.pch'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk"**

This path is strange and upper letter of library name is changed lower letter when I click warning message. For example, Parse/Parse.h to parse/Parse.h

Please help me if you have any suggestion.

Comment: If it's pod related issue and nothing works then delete the workspace and Pod folder. Just keep the Podfile and Podfile.lock files and run pod install

Comment: I've already tried that way but warnings still showing.

Comment: Deleting the Pod folder and run pod install worked for me. But I deleted the entire app folder and re-downloaded from Github first. Not sure if that's what made the difference for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter the same problem when I duplicate configuration of debug in xcode. I resolve this by run pod update, the problem is cocoapod need update. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Sometimes running pod update is not enough and one has to delete the pods first.
Would like to know why this issue is happening though

Comment: @smartom:  I have the same issue in Xcode 9.1. Couldn't solve the issue. How can I rectify that.